# How do you make Text double-clickable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application, kotlin-multiplatform, double-click

I've got a `Text` control in my JetPack Compose desktop application that I'd like to be double-clickable so that users can add its value to a filter. The text is displayed within a `LazyColumn` as one of several values.

I know you can make it `clickable` with `Modifier.clickable`, but how do I make it *double-clickable* so that it isn't added by accident via a single-click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `detectTapGestures(onDoubleTap= {})` which is available inside PointerInputScope as

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {
    
    val context = LocalContext.current
    
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit){
          detectTapGestures(
              onDoubleTap = {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "Double Tapped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
              }
          )  
        },
       text =  "Some Text to Double Tap",
        fontSize = 26.sp
    )
}
```

Comment: Wow, so simple and so unituitive at the same time for a desktop application. I guess I need to try to think more smartphony in future as this totaly makes sense in this context.

Comment: I think gestures and drawings, Modifier.drawX modifiers, are the most innovative and easy to use part of Compose. Easy to add gestures or draw anything above or behind any Composable using modifiers unlike building custom views.